# Jquery - Query future element without interval

Tags: jquery

I have an application that dynamically builds html components and throw them to the page.

I would like perform an action on all future elements. for example, all future input elements with colorpicker class should run this:

```
$('input.colorpicker').colorpicker()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DOMSubtreeModified` event and call the initializers.

```
$('body').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() { 
    $('input.colorpicker').colorpicker();
});
```

Whenever an element is added to the body dynamically the DOMSubtreeModified event is triggered and the initializer is called.

It would be helpful if you could maintain a list of all the elements that have already been initialized and then call the initializers on those that have not been initialized to prevent unnecessary effects of initializing something that already has been initialized.

`DOMSubtreeModified` is supported on Chrome, FF and IE 9+.